# sed pattern for "1.2", "1.2.3", "1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.4.5", …

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to use `sed` for matching this pattern: it has multiple parts, each part is separated by a full stop, and the content is a non-empty sequence of digits, like:

```
"1", "1.2", "192.168.0.1", …
```

Does `sed` support grouping a sequence of regex as a group and use `+` or `*`, etc. on it?

I'm grateful for any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are matching patten you can use `grep` as:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*'
```

In `sed` you can do:

```
sed  -r 's/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/replacement/'
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/X5XhZ)

Comment: In fact I am matching it, and then replace it. Does `sed` support the `-E` option? I can't find that in its man page.

Comment: @Ryan Li: I've updated my answer and have provided a working link.

Comment: Thanks! I was using `sed -r`, but was stuck with Perlish `\d`…